# Why are tag suggestions and votes tied together?

Tags: discussion, support

I noticed that a new tag `block-chain` was created and wanted to add a synonym `blockchain` to it because I frequently encounter either writing. The latter seems to be the correct one so maybe another kind of edit would be appropriate. Anyway. what really confused me is the error I got when I tried to suggest the tag. The second paragraph reads like you'd need 2500 reputation to suggest edits and independently of that you'd need 5 answer score for that tag to approve/reject the suggestion. But it seems like a suggestion also works as a vote.

I can see this as being intentional but I'm not sure. I'm not really seeing why you'd be able to vote on suggested tags with less than 2500 reputation. If the answer score is the important part why not just limit it to the answer score (and maybe increase it)?

[image: screenshot of synonym suggestion and the error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What really confused me is the error I got when I tried to suggest the
>   tag. The second paragraph reads like you'd need 2500 reputation to
>   suggest edits and independently of that you'd need 5 answer score for
>   that tag to approve/reject the suggestion.

You need both.  You need 2,500 reputation to vote on suggested tag synonyms.  You need to be a user with an answer with a score 5 or more (and 2,500 reputation) to suggest a synonym yourself.  An alternative approach is to discuss it with the community, and a moderator after a short amount of time, will suggest the synonym themselves.

> I'm not really seeing why you'd be able to vote on suggested tags with
>   less than 2500 reputation. If the answer score is the important part
>   why not just limit it to the answer score (and maybe increase it)?

We are trying to avoid a situation where a subject matter expert on **oranges** suggests that **apples** would be a good synonym for **oranges** because they are both **fruit**.  Getting a score of 5 or more in a tag is a trivial task.

Comment: Worth pointing out that, if a tag has a single question, it might be easier to just retag that single question to the better tag.  Of course in this case, the other tag does not even exist, and the 1 question that does exist is out of scope.  I wouldn't personally approve a synonym in this case anyways, without the current tag being modified to clarify, that the tag shouldn't even be used here at Superuser.